# Changing the selected order status in the order comments section

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order, order-status, edit-order

When commenting on an order, you can also change the order status at the same time.

For some orders, the drop-down does not have the *current* order status selected by default, so it's easy(due to human error) to accidentally change the order status when you intend to only create a comment.

For example an order in **payment_review(state)/payment_review(status)** has **processing(state)/awaiting_dispatch(status)** selected by default, like so:

[image]

My thoughts are to either:
**A)** Change the drop-down so it always has the *current* status selected by default.
**B)** Remove the ability to change the status here altogether. We do all our status changing from the order grid so this is acceptable in our case.

I can't find anything on this issue, so I'm hoping for some advice from someone who knows more about this functionality and the best way to go about it.

I've re-trained the staff to be more aware of this field but the issue continues. I'm currently using magento ce 1.9.3.1

Comment: by default status dropdown value is current order status

Comment: @GopalPatel I've included an example above. For at least one of my order status' it's not using the default. Do you think this is an issue isolated to my setup?